# Pass in dynamic href using Django include template tag AND url tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to reuse a component and invoke it multiple times using the `include` tag.
But when I want to pass in a url, I can't figure out the syntax.

Usually it would be something like:

`<a href="{% url 'slug' %}">{{link_title}}</a>`

But as I'm already using an `include`, I want to do something equivalent to:

```
# parent template:
{% include 'my-template.html' with slug='someslug' link_title='My Link Title' %}

# include template:
<a href="{% url '{{slug}}' %}">{{link_title}}</a>
```

I currently get `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch` from this code.
How can I pass the dynamic `slug` into the `url` safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a quotes issue.

`{% url slug %}`

should work